# How to use tableModel to visualize filtered information in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, rowfilter

I need to develop a GUI with an interactive Table, where the user must be able to  insert rows manually or import/save the information from/to an Excel file. Lets say I have a bunch of personal information in the file (age, name, address). I need a reusable panel, on which I can select a certain "age", and then show JUST the people with that age.

I am thinking about two strategies:

OPTION 1:

- Read the Excel file and copy all the information into a List < Object[] >. Each object contains personal information (age, name, address).
- If I want to filter by "age": read the List<> looking for the objects with a certain "age".
- Update the tableModel with those objects (tableModel has a List< Object[]> as attribute).
- Update the jTable with the updated tableModel.

  ```
      inputsTableModel.inputsTableDataList = temp_list;
  inputsTable.setModel(inputsTableModel);
  panel1.add(inputsTableScroller, "2, 12, 3, 1, fill, fill");
  inputsTableScroller.setViewportView(inputsTable);
  ```

OPTION 2:

- Read from Excel and copy to tableModel directly (tableModel will contain ALL the information).
- Filter information in the model, and update jTable.

My point is: if the user wants to manually edit the table and then save the changes to an Excel file, Option 2 is clearly a better solution. But is it possible? Is it possible to filter information in the tableModel, and then update the table?

On the other hand, how can I implement this modify&save issue when using Option1?

Comment: Regarding OPTION 2: did you take a look at row filtering in the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting ?

Comment: Option 3: `extend AbstractTableModel` to use an Excel file.

Comment: @trashgod Yes indeed, that would be my choice too. This may be of some interest: http://code.google.com/p/exceltablemodel/source/browse/trunk/exceltablemodel/src/main/java/com/googlecode/exceltablemodel/ExcelTableModel.java?r=6 but it requires Apache POI

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: Excellent! (if you'll forgive the pun); I defer to your answer.

Comment: God... that sorter object sounds good. Lets try :D

Comment: btw, I am using:
public class InputsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel

Comment: and http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html for read/write Excel using jxl framework. But I will turn to Apache POI if I find there is a good reason ;)

Comment: @boblinwien I would no longer consider JXL because it does not support Excel 2007 format (.xslx) and it is not maintained for over 3 years. POI does not suffer from those caveats.